# Flex-wrap on Android 4.4.2 doesn't work

Tags: android, html, css, flexbox

Currently I'm working on a website where I use a lot of flexbox. I'm now testing on Samsung Galaxy Note II which runs on Android 4.4.2.

This [website](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) says all flexbox properties should be useable. However, flex-wrap doesn't work on my test device.

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us32v980/1/) to illustrate what I want to achieve. Using floats or something else isn't an option.

I used this CSS to make the wrapping happing:

```
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Is there a way to make wrapping work on Android 4.4.2? Thanks!

Comment: So it doesn't wrap at all?

Comment: Nope, no wrapping in sight. I made this example so you can test it out yourself. This Fiddle doesn't wrap on Android 4.4.2 while caniuse says it should.

Comment: I don't have 4.4.2 so I can't test...I was just clarifying "doesn't work" for other users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25337814/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I already read that page. Flexbox does work on Android 4.4.2, but flex-wrap doesn't.

Comment: I posted the link because one answer (not the accepted one) may be useful.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem with Android 4.4.2 flex wrapping? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @IlyaKushlianski no I didn't. Don't think you can fix it honestly

Comment: I bought my htc phone in 2014. Is the situation with flex better now with Internet browser on Android?